Error when trying to convert JSON to a dataframe in R
When I run the following code in R, I keep getting an error.
earnings_pull <- as.data.frame(rjson::fromJSON(file=paste("https://api.twelvedata.com/earnings?symbol=", "AAPL", "&outputsize=1&apikey=", twelve_data_api, sep="")))

I get the following error:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

This is what the data looks like in JSON:
{"meta":{"symbol":"AAPL","name":"Apple Inc","currency":"USD","exchange":"NASDAQ","mic_code":"XNGS","exchange_timezone":"America/New_York"},"earnings":[{"date":"2025-10-29","time":"Time Not Supplied","eps_estimate":null,"eps_actual":null,"difference":null,"surprise_prc":null}],"status":"ok"}

Please help.

Use paste0() instead of paste()

I tried paste0(), still getting the same error.

jsonlite::fromJSON(s)$earnings returning a data.frame, where s your JSON.

Your JSON object when parsed becomes a list from which you can extract two data frames like so:
library(jsonlite)

my_json <- '{"meta":{"symbol":"AAPL","name":"Apple Inc","currency":"USD","exchange":"NASDAQ","mic_code":"XNGS","exchange_timezone":"America/New_York"},"earnings":[{"date":"2025-10-29","time":"Time Not Supplied","eps_estimate":null,"eps_actual":null,"difference":null,"surprise_prc":null}],"status":"ok"}'

my_df_list <- fromJSON(my_json)

meta_df <- as.data.frame(my_df_list$meta)

earnings_df <- as.data.frame(my_df_list$earnings)

